# Can we run multiple google cloud pipelines on the same data simultaneously?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

Let's say I have a pipeline that loads data from a Storage file and loads it into a Big Query Table. Before this pipeline is completed, can I run another pipeline that does the same operation on the same file & table?

My assumption is that it should fail. Also how would we be able to trigger the second pipeline? (I run Apache Beam code in Eclipse; it doesn't allow second execution, when one class is running) Can we use CLI to run?

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to do this, but yes you can. It won't fail unless the id of the pipeline is the same.

Comment: Thanks! We are just thinking if someone could accidentally trigger a replica by the same pipeline and if it would run or not. The id of the pipeline would be auto generated, so it should be unique. Won't there be any access issue for the table and the file as the two jobs are going to be trying to access the same resources?

Comment: No. Google handle all that for you ;-)

Comment: Hi @GrahamPolley, could you post this comments as an answer? So that others know the issue is solved :-)

Comment: If your pipeline is configured to append data to the BigQuery table, you will end up with duplicate results (from both pipelines) afaik. You'd have to handle it manually

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd want to do this, but yes you can. It won't fail unless the id of the pipeline is the same. Dataflow will read/write in parallel.